# Monotouch ad-hoc distro

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

I've managed to get it to do what i think is an adhoc build and inside the bin folder there's an appName.app folder

is that folder the distro?

if it is - how can i put it onto a web server for people to install and test for me?

is this possible?

w://

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I over-estimated how ad-hoc the ad-hoc is

http://forums.monotouch.net/yaf_postst256_Provisioning-an-iPhone-via-email.aspx

:(